# SQL Server on Linux - Launchpad service issue

Tags: python, sql-server, linux

To use Python on SQL Server Linux, I am configuring the SQL Server launchpad service as per directions at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-machine-learning?toc=%2Fsql%2Fmachine-learning%2Ftoc.json&view=sql-server-ver15).

When I try to restart the service by below command, I get this error:

> Failed to restart mssql-launchpadd.service: Unit not found.

I also tried using word "launchpad" (with just 1 'd' below) but same error.  Could you please provide any insights on this? Thanks.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mssql-launchpadd
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using, could follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.X

Comment: Out of curosity, have you tried `sudo systemctl restart mssql-launchpadd.service`?

Comment: I have - with no luck..